# what is the reason of the distance?

Tags: html, css

when i hover over my link and li , there is 1 or less px distance , at the first i wrote padding : 0 10px and when i changed top & bottom's padding to 1px and more that distance Disappears.
can anyone tell me why this is happenig? thank you

```css
.menu {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #e0f0ff;
  direction: rtl;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.menu ul li {
  float: right;
}
ul::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
 <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">main page</a></li>
          <li><a href="">shopping</a></li>
          <li><a href="">working with us</a></li>
          <li><a href="">adds</a></li>
          <li><a href="">about us </a></li>
          <li><a href="">contact us </a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately your question is not very clear. Could you explain what you mean by distance? Perhaps an image showing which bits you are talking about would help

Comment: sorry for that, i mean when at the first i put the link's top and bottom's padding to 0 and the right and left paddings to 10px and then i hover over it there is a little distance bitween li background bottoms and the ul's border but when i change the top and bottom's padding to 1px that distance in hover mode dissapear.i couldn't find the reason in google and even in stack.

Comment: @zahrarajabi Welcome to Stack Overflow! Instead of trying to explain what you did, please update your question to **show** what you did with code. You can make a couple stack snippets in the question to show what you mean. When you say "link" are you referring to the `<a>` or the `<li>` and `<a>`. It's better to say what **element** you are referring to.